# nginx ignoring server_name or whole virtual host

Tags: nginx

I have this nginx setup:

```
# Default server configuration
#
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server ipv6only=on;
    server_name _;

    root /usr/share/nginx/html;

    index index.php index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }

    error_page 404 /404.html;
    error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
        root /usr/share/nginx/html;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }

    location ~ /\.ht {
        deny all;
    }
}
```

owncloud:

```
upstream php-handler {
  server 127.0.0.1:9000;
}

add_header X-Content-Type-Options nosniff;
add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
add_header X-XSS-Protection "1; mode=block";
add_header X-Robots-Tag none;

server {
  listen 80;
  server_name cloud.example.com;
  # enforce https
  return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
}

server {
  listen 443 ssl;
  server_name cloud.example.com;


  ssl_certificate /etc/ssl/nginx/server.crt;
  ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/nginx/server.key;

  ssl_ciphers 'ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:DHE-DSS-AES128-GCM-SHA256:kEDH+AESGCM:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:DHE-DSS-AES128-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA256:DHE-DSS-AES256-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:AES128-GCM-SHA256:AES256-GCM-SHA384:AES128-SHA256:AES256-SHA256:AES128-SHA:AES256-SHA:AES:CAMELLIA:DES-CBC3-SHA:!aNULL:!eNULL:!EXPORT:!DES:!RC4:!MD5:!PSK:!aECDH:!EDH-DSS-DES-CBC3-SHA:!EDH-RSA-DES-CBC3-SHA:!KRB5-DES-CBC3-SHA';
  ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
  ssl_dhparam /etc/nginx/ssl/dhparam.pem;

  # Add headers to serve security related headers
  add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=15768000; includeSubDomains; preload;";

  # Path to the root of your installation
  root /var/www/owncloud/;

  # set max upload size
  client_max_body_size 10G;
  fastcgi_buffers 64 4K;

  rewrite ^/caldav(.*)$ /remote.php/caldav$1 redirect;
  rewrite ^/carddav(.*)$ /remote.php/carddav$1 redirect;
  rewrite ^/webdav(.*)$ /remote.php/webdav$1 redirect;

  index index.php;
  error_page 403 /core/templates/403.php;
  error_page 404 /core/templates/404.php;

  location = /robots.txt {
    allow all;
    log_not_found off;
    access_log off;
    }

  location ~ ^/(?:\.htaccess|data|config|db_structure\.xml|README){
    deny all;
  }

  location / {
   # The following 2 rules are only needed with webfinger
   rewrite ^/.well-known/host-meta /public.php?service=host-meta last;
   rewrite ^/.well-known/host-meta.json /public.php?service=host-meta-json last;

   rewrite ^/.well-known/carddav /remote.php/carddav/ redirect;
   rewrite ^/.well-known/caldav /remote.php/caldav/ redirect;

   rewrite ^(/core/doc/[^\/]+/)$ $1/index.html;

   try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php;
   }

location ~ \.php(?:$|/) {
   fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
   include fastcgi_params;
   fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
   fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
   fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;
   fastcgi_param PHP_VALUE "upload_max_filesize = 8000M
   post_max_size = 8000M
   output_buffering = 0";
   fastcgi_param HTTPS on;
   }

   # Optional: set long EXPIRES header on static assets
   location ~* \.(?:jpg|jpeg|gif|bmp|ico|png|css|js|swf)$ {
       expires 30d;
       # Optional: Don't log access to assets
         access_log off;
   }

}
```

mediawiki

```
server {
        server_name wiki.example.com;
        listen 80;

        root /var/www/mediawiki;
        index index.html index.php;
        autoindex off;

        access_log /var/log/nginx/access-mediawiki.log;
        error_log /var/log/nginx/error-mediawiki.log;

        location / {
                try_files $uri $uri/ @rewrite;
        }

        location @rewrite {
                rewrite ^/(.*)$ /index.php?title=$1&$args;
        }

        location ^~ /maintenance/ {
                return 403;
        }

        location ~ \.php$ {
                include fastcgi_params;
                fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
        }

        location ~* \.(js|css|png|jpg|jpeg|gif|ico)$ {
                try_files $uri /index.php;
                expires max;
                log_not_found off;
        }

        location = /_.gif {
                expires max;
                empty_gif;
        }

        location ^~ /cache/ {
                deny all;
        }

        location /dumps {
                root /var/www/mediawiki/local;
                autoindex on;
        }

}
```

When I am accessing `cloud.example.com` everything is fine. But when I go to `wiki.example.com` I am redirected to `https://wiki.example.com` and get the answer from the `owncloud` server. So it seems, that the wiki server is ignored.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the `includeSubDomains` from your HSTS header.

**includeSubDomains** *Optional*

> If this optional parameter is specified, this rule applies to all of the site's subdomains as well.

**How the browser handles it**

> The first time your site is accessed using HTTPS and it returns the Strict-Transport-Security header, the browser records this information, so that future attempts to load the site using HTTP will automatically use HTTPS instead.
>
> When the expiration time specified by the Strict-Transport-Security header elapses, the next attempt to load the site via HTTP will proceed as normal instead of automatically using HTTPS.
>
> Whenever the Strict-Transport-Security header is delivered to the browser, it will update the expiration time for that site, so sites can refresh this information and prevent the timeout from expiring. Should it be necessary to disable Strict Transport Security, setting the max-age to 0 (over a https connection) will immediately expire the Strict-Transport-Security header, allowing access via http.

Source: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/HTTP_strict_transport_security